# IF NOT EXIST NOT WORKING

Tags: mysql, sql, not-exists

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `name`='Rutvij' AND `lang`='python')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('Rutvij', 'python', 25)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE user SET `name`='Kanzaria' WHERE `name`='Rutvij'
    END
```

I am trying the above query in phpmyadmin sql area. I am using xampp. It is throwing error stating that

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user)
>       SELECT name FROM use' at line 1

I have also tried the below code

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='Rutvij' AND lang='python')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO user VALUES ('Rutvij', 'python', 25)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO user VALUES ('Kanzaria', 'python', 25)
    END
```

Struggling for so long. Kindly help. Thanks!!

Comment: if as a routing option(not the function) only works in procedures and triggers.You might also want to look into REPLACE INTO.

Comment: I thought you needed a `then` statement with `if` in `mysql`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't permit `if` logic, unless you are in a programming block (stored procedure, trigger, or function).

Fortunately, you can do the same with `WHERE` logic:

```
INSERT INTO user 
    SELECT 'Rutvij', 'python', 25
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE name = 'Rutvij' AND lang = 'python')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Kanzaria', 'python', 25
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE name = 'Rutvij' AND lang = 'python');
```

MySQL should process the `SELECT` before the `INSERT`, so only one row should be inserted.

Or, you can do this as two `INSERT`s but in the opposite order:

```
INSERT INTO user 
    SELECT 'Kanzaria', 'python', 25
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE name = 'Rutvij' AND lang = 'python');

INSERT INTO user 
    SELECT 'Rutvij', 'python', 25
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE name = 'Rutvij' AND lang = 'python');
```

Comment: What if I want to update when the record exists? Then what shall i do? If not exists then insert else update.

Comment: @RutvijKanzaria . . . You would use `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a query, this would be an sql script with control flow logic, which is not allowed in mysql outside stored programs (procedures, functions, triggers). Even if you encapsulated the above code into a stored procedure it would not work because exist / not exists can only be used in subqueries.

I would do the following:

1. Create a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)
2. Declare an integer variable
3. Using [select into](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)  fetch the count of rows where `name='Rutvij' AND lang='python'` into your variable.
4. Use the if statement to do the insertion based on the number of records.